# Extracting a specific number from a dataset in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R that includes these columns: (team, `match id`, `win?`, player, score). There are 8 rows for every unique match_id (4 players on each team).

I want to extract the opposite teams score as well into the dataframe under df$opponent_score.

Imagine it would be some kind of if then statement? If df$`match id` and df$team are equal then use df$score of non matching df$team. How could I format this? Or is there any easier way to do so then using if-then?

The answer seems obvious but I am newer to R, so I appreciate any help!

Data Example:

```
  team              `match id`                           `win?` player score
  <chr>             <chr>                                <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>
1 Epsilon           a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8 L      Dqvee      2
2 Epsilon           a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8 L      Hawqeh     2
3 Epsilon           a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8 L      Nathan     2
4 Epsilon           a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8 L      Vortex     2
5 Luminosity Gaming a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8 W      JKap       6
6 Luminosity Gaming a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8 W      John       6
```

Comment: Based on your data showed, I don't find any `match id` to be same as 'team'

Comment: Can you show the expected output as well.  The description and your data is creating some confusion

Comment: So for every row. You have the 'match id' team and score. I want to create a new column of opp_score that is what the other team scored in that match. Every match_id has 8 unique rows of 4 players from both teams. In this example under opp_score for Epsilon it would be 6. Under opp_score for Luminosity Gaming it would be 2.

Comment: From the data showed, I see `a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8` are used by teams 'Epsilon' and 'Luminosity Gaming'.  So, I guess your opposite scores is 6 6 6 6 2 2?  But, what if there are more than two team gets matched with 'match id'

Comment: For every unique match_id in my dataset there are only two possible teams. The match ID is in reference to their game vs eachother.

Comment: I  updated my solution.  Hope it works for you

Comment: @akrun It appears your solution is not working. I am getting random results under opposite_score. It appears as if it is not matching by matchID at all but instead a random team match. There are duplicate team names throughout the dataset. But only 8 rows for every match ID.

Comment: I assume that you have only two 'team' per each `match id`.  If that is the case it would work because in my code, I am taking the `distinct` or `unique` rows of 'team', 'match id' and 'score'

Comment: Can you please check the `df1 %>% group_by(`match id`) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(team))`  It should be a all 2.  Similarly, I assume the 'score' to be the same

Comment: Do you have missing values or NA in the dataset?

Comment: I get 56 when using that

Comment: That is not possible.  Have you loaded `plyr` package as well.  If that is the case, then the `summarise` from `plyr` mask the `dplyr` summarise.  You can either do this on a fresh R session with only `dplyr` loaded or use explicitly `dplyr::summarise`

Comment: That was the issue. Now I get 2 for every match ID.

Comment: Any potential reason why the solution wouldn't work if there are 2 values for every match ID @akrun

Comment: I couldn't find any reason, because the `rev` on that 2 unique values flips it reverse when we are grouping by 'matchid'.  You said earlier that you are getting 2 for every match ID

Comment: My solution was based on what you showed as input.  It works on the data you showed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224940/discussion-between-karsen-mitsche-and-akrun).

Comment: Please create a small but reproducible example of your data using `dput`. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) link explains that in more detail. Keep only the columns that are required for the question and drop others. Also show us expected output for the data you share. You don't have to share your actual data you can create a fake dataset that is similar to your original dataset but make sure that dataset covers all possible scenarios that are present in your original set so that we don't have a situation where the answer works on the fake dataset but not on real dataset.

Answer (score 2):

We could do a group by `rev` on the unique rows and then join with the original data

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   distinct(team, `match id`, score) %>% 
   group_by(`match id`) %>% 
   mutate(opposite_score = rev(score)) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   right_join(df1) %>%
   select(names(df1), opposite_score)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
#  team              `match id`                           `win?` player score opposite_score
#  <chr>             <chr>                                <chr>  <chr>  <int>          <int>
#1 Epsilon           a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8 L      Dqvee      2              6
#2 Epsilon           a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8 L      Hawqeh     2              6
#3 Epsilon           a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8 L      Nathan     2              6
#4 Epsilon           a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8 L      Vortex     2              6
#5 Luminosity Gaming a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8 W      JKap       6              2
#6 Luminosity Gaming a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8 W      John       6              2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(team = c("Epsilon", "Epsilon", "Epsilon", "Epsilon", 
"Luminosity Gaming", "Luminosity Gaming"), 
 `match id` = c("a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8", 
"a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8", "a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8", 
"a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8", "a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8", 
"a6185d12-3133-5a48-aa52-b4407f94bfd8"), `win?` = c("L", "L", 
"L", "L", "W", "W"), player = c("Dqvee", "Hawqeh", "Nathan", 
"Vortex", "JKap", "John"), score = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am getting "NA" as a return for opponent_score when using this. Any idea why?

Comment: @KarsenMitsche do you have matching values for `match_id` and `team_name`?  Can you please update your post with a small reproducible example so that I can test it

Comment: Just added it in: Also, I was using sample names before for the columns. But with the actual column names this is what I am using code wise: WWSNDData$OppScore <- with(WWSNDData, score[match(`match id`,team)])

Comment: @KarsenMitsche based on the data, the column name is `match id` and what is the `team_name` column?  is it `team`